# Nativescript-socketio : Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-socketio"

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Running [this](https://github.com/agrawal-mohit/fundoo/tree/debug) application on Mac, tns 2.4.0 npm 3.10.9
which uses the [nativescript-socketio](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-socketio) module.
Error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-socketio", relative to: app/tns_modules/
    com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:514)
    com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:509)
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:17)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
    android.os.Handler
```

This error comes up in tns2.4.0 but not in tns2.5.0.

Comment: The link to your application is dead. What exactly is your question? Maybe: why the problem only appears with Nativescript version 2.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added [moduleId:module.id] in your component.

eg:

@Component({
moduleId:module.id,
selector:'ns-selector',
templateUrl:'selector.component.html'})